# How to pass any APDU command from currently selected applet to another applet?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, javacard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

**Question:** Suppose there are multiple instance of an Applet. Currently one Applet instance is selected. Is it possible to pass any APDU command from the selected Applet to another Applet instance? I did not find such any method in JavaCard API version 3.0.4.

**Details:** While researching the document "Expresspay Mobile Specifications v1.2" for implementing the 'Application Selection' service, I get stuck in the following section 5.3.6. As the document is not open source, I'm quoting the selective part:

> "If an Expresspay Mobile Application is selected over the contact less
>   interface using the Partial AID, then it shall pass the SELECT command
>   and subsequent commands to the activated Expresspay Mobile Application
>   instance (which may or may not be the application being selected)."

It states that I need to pass a SELECT command from currently selected applet to the another applet (which is *activated*!).
But I did not find anything in JavaCard API that will pass any command from one applet to another applet. I searched on Oracle Community and found [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1751909) with no reply!

**Edit:** Suppose there are three instances A1, A2, A3 of applet A. Applet A has a shareable flag object  `flag`, containing AID of "active" instance, say AID of A2. (Assume that `flag` may be pre-initialized). Currently instance A1 is selected. Now the terminal sends any APDU command, that will come to instance A1. A1 will check the `flag` and find out that `flag` contains AID of A2. So, A1 will pass the APDU command to A2 for further processing. My question is how A1 instance send any APDU command to A2 instance?

Comment: You want to select the other instance?

Comment: @Ellisun Not exactly, I need to process the SELECT command into the other isntance.

Comment: You can send SELECT command with `File occurrence` bits to `Next occurence`.

Comment: The (Partial AID) SELECT command will come to the currently selected applet, then it(currently selected) applet will take decision to send the command to another instance. Question: how to do it? It's not about `Next occurence`.

Comment: I don't know your requirement.

Comment: @Ellisun, Ok, I'm editing my question with an example.

Comment: Is "*the activated Expresspay Mobile Application instance*" the one that the partial AID in the SELECT command refers to?

Comment: May or may not. The partial AID is same for all instance. The currently selected applet instance will find out which applet instance is 'activate' and send the command to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "If an Expresspay Mobile Application is selected over the contact less interface using the Partial AID, then it shall pass the SELECT command and subsequent commands to the activated Expresspay Mobile Application instance (which may or may not be the application being selected)."

Most Java Card smartcards that I came across so far supported selection by partial AID (while the Java Card RE specification has no requirement on this, the GlobalPlatform card specification (see section "*Explicit Selection on Basic Logical Channel*") does mandate support for selection by partial AID). Hence, the SELECT command will typically cause the currently selected applet to change to an applet with a matching AID.

So if that newly selected applet is not necessarily the "*activated* Expresspay Mobile Application instance", then you could possibly pass on all communication through a shareable interface that is provided by the *activated* applet instance.

Assume that the SELECT (by partial AID) command causes *B* to be the currently selected applet and that *A* is the "activated" applet instance. *A* would then implement a shareable interface and provides a method that can be used to pass commands to and return responses from *A*. *B* can then get access to that shareable interface through `getShareableInterfaceObject(AID of A, ...)` and can use that interface to call into *A* in order to forward commands to it. The actual APDU communcation would still have to be done in applet *B* though. Moreover, it seems rather inefficient to pass commands and responses between *B* and *A*. Also, this would not switch the currently selected applet to *A*, hence subsequent commands would still go to *B* and would also need to be passed through that interface.

A much better approach seems to be to let the GlobalPlatform OPEN handle the above requirement (and I assume that's how this is meant to be implemented). For a SELECT (by partial AID) command, the OPEN (see section "*Explicit Selection on Basic Logical Channel*" of the GP Card specification) will automatically choose the first **selectable** applet instance. Hence, in order to mark one of your applet instances as *active*, you would actually deactivate all other applet instances for the contactless interface. In order to do this, your managing applet (CRS application) would need to have the *Contactless Activation* privilege (and/or each applet instance would need the *Contactless Self-Activation* privilege to manage its own activation). You can then use the GlobalPlatform API to manage the activation state of each applet instance. See Amendment C to the GP Card specification. The interesting methods of the GP card API seem to be `GPCLSystem.getGPCLRegistryEntry(AID)` and `GPCLRegistryEntry.setCLState(state)`.